# blackberry install an application twice

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I developed a Blackberry app and want to install it twice, as two separate apps, on the same device. I want the exact same app installed again, but the second installation should not overwrite the first one.

Which setting identifies the BlackBerry app? Is it in the AppDescriptor?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying in the second paragraph....!

Comment: ...what Michael finally answered. I wanted to know what I had to change in my application in order to have a different application. The answer is the "output file name" in App descriptor. When you change it, your application is recognized as a different app as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, when editing the Application Descriptor, go to the 'build' tab.   There is a field for the "Output file name".   That filename distinguishes apps from one another.

However, you will run into another problem, as your second installation will collide with the first one, as all the java classes have the same packages and names.  So you will need to use something like [jarjarlinks](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to tweak the package names a little bit before installing the second app.

Comment: the problem you described in the second paragraph didn't occur. I have installed many of the same app with just another output file name. INstalling them is not problem. Maybe you meant running two of them at the same time. I didn't try this. Maybe this doesn't work. But running one at a time works perfectly.